# Theorems in a book

Tags: theorems

I would like to write a theorem in the format of a book. So I write

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
```

but after that I write

```
\begin{theom}
```

and it does not compile. Can someone please help me write a theorem in a book?

Comment: We need a miminal example. Have you defined theom by a command or did you import it from some package?

Comment: If you search this site for `theorem`, you'll get a lot of relevant results.

Answer (score 13):

As a start, I would suggest reading [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2ε](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf). It will give some idea of what LaTeX is all about and how to format a regular document.

Specific to your question, here is a small sample of what you might be after:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
This is some text, with the following theorem.
\begin{theorem}
My first theorem. \label{mytheorem}
\end{theorem}
Theorem~\ref{mytheorem} is pretty awesome.
\end{document}
```

Compiling this twice (to allow for appropriate referencing), you obtain:

[image: My first theorem]

If you're interested in numbering your theorem differently (say, having it reset with every `\chapter` and have the chapter number form part of the theorem number, as in `chapter.theorem`), you could use:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
```

The command breakdown as well as the meaning of the parameters is available from "[Help with `\newtheorem`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-20.html)".

Specific theorem-formatting packages (like [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) or [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), say) are also available that might be of help. However, this depends on exactly what kind of formatting you're after.

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: @Werner: Why did you define the counter `theorem`?

Comment: @Marco: Arg... that was not needed. Another instinctive measure when dealing with numbered stuff. With no complaint of an already defined counter `theorem`, I assumed it was necessary. I've removed it from my MWE.